# How I can download my beta test release from app hub? I have zune url but... - wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, testing, download, marketplace

This is a simple questions:

I've developed my first app for windows phone 7 (Mango). I have created a new release in the marketplace for beta test.

I have received one confirm email about this process. All is ok. But now, in this email, there  is a Url like this:

zune://navigate/?appid=46546c45-7b41-11ae-b78e-268334559f0ac

In theory, I have to send this url to beta testing people of my list. But Where I or they have to write this url for download the app?

In zune? In the marketplace? I don't know what I have to do with this url....

Thanks guys,

JPe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you submitted the app for beta testing, you needed to specify the live ids of some testers. This link (zune://) can be used to install the application through Zune. You need to send this link to those testers whose live ids you entered there. **Just paste the link in any browser and it will open with Zune.**

The link will not work for anyone else, but for the specified live ids.

If your live id is not in the beta tester live ids list, I am not sure that you can test the app with your live id. I'd suggest to add your live id to the list.

And by the way, you cannot access a beta app through the Marketplace, the only way is through Zune with the given link.

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Only I have to copy this url in a web broser.

Comment: The solution given below in the 2nd answer is working for me, while from PC it did not.

Answer (score 0):

I have found in most cases the beta links only work when opened from a Windows 7 device, opening the link on a PC through Zune either gets a "app not available" or "app not available for your country".
There doesn't seem to be any setting in the marketplace to get around this so it may be by design.

No word yet on if this is fixed with the web marketplace but I doubt it since the Beta apps only give a Zune link

Comment: There are a restriction in Zune about the country that your computer (or your live account (I am not sure yet of this)) is configurated. In this way, there are one web where you can download a script for modify the regist of windows. You should to close Zune before to exec it script. After exec it, I have never had more problems about the location and I can download my beta versions using Zune without any problem.  This web is:  http://www.withinwindows.com/2009/09/17/restore-zune-4-0s-missing-features/     Take a look!